# Finding names for parents of Louis Spitzer who was born 1826 in Prussia?

Tags: birth-records, 1820s, prussia

Who were the parents of Louis Spitzer born March 5, 1826 (per Death Certificate) in Gleiwitz, Silesia, Prussia?

He was jewish at death, but could have been Christian at birth.

Comment: Asking for 'any information' doesn't really fit with the purpose of this site which is about asking targeted questions and getting specific answers in reply. Do you have a single piece of information that you would like to find next, and can you tell us how you know where and when he was born? That will help us avoid repeating work you've already done. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the same Louis Spitzer who travelled from Hamburg to New York in the Miles arriving on 19 Jan 1850?  If so, a link to that source and any other records that you have in his timeline would make useful background for your question.  I found it at Ancestry where there seems to be an 1870 Federal Census record for the same.  The names of his children may be helpful to sort any parent candidates that you find.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes I have that record of his immigration and the census.